# how to find two strings without overlap in python

Tags: string, input, overlap

I want my code to be able to find strings: 'AB' and 'BA' without overlapping. I tried:

```
word = input()

x = word.find('AB')
y = word.find('BA')
if x != -1:
    if y != -1:
        print('YES')
    else:
        print('NO')
```

but it doesn't work well, for example,
if word = BAB,
the output: 'YES' but there is an overlap in that and I want the output to be a 'NO'.
another example:
word = ABBA
output: 'YES', which is True.
I want my code to be able to find one of my strings and then try the other one and vice versa, so there can be no overlaps between them
can anyone help me?

Comment: I am sorry it is not clear to me what you mean by overlap. can you add some more examples of input > expected behavior > actual behavior? like, is abba an overlap? is ABA? What about BCB and ASD. do you only want to see if there is an overlap of AB and BA, and what does 'overlap' mean?

Comment: I edited my question and added more desired instances,i hope it would be what you have asked